# Mirror variable returning a nil

Tags: swift

This is working as expected

```
struct ProgrammingLanguage {
    let name: String?
}
let language = ProgrammingLanguage(name: "Swift")
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: language.name)
print(mirror.children.first?.value)

// Optional("Swift")
```

When removing the optional it prints out a nil

```
struct ProgrammingLanguage {
    let name: String
}
let language = ProgrammingLanguage(name: "Swift")
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: language.name)
print(mirror.children.first?.value)

// nil
```

Can someone explain why a value exists for optionals and otherwise it's a nil?

Comment: Change `let name: String` to `var name: String!`

Comment: An optional is an enum, its child is its associated value. A non optional String has no children. You have to get the value through a child of ProgrammingLanguage mirror.

Comment: @Sulthan I see but `print(mirror.children)` output some collection. How is that when String has no children..

Comment: @ViktorKucera An empty collection.

Comment: @Sulthan You are right. Please make it an answer and I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [Mirror documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror), `Mirror` is:

> A representation of the substructure and display style of an instance of any type.

The problem is that `String` has no substructure therefore it has no children. To inspect its value using `Mirror`, you have to take the `children` of `ProgrammingLanguage`.

It works for optional `String` because the `Optional<T>` itself can be inspected and its only child is its associated value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
struct ProgrammingLanguage {
    let name: String
}
let language = ProgrammingLanguage(name: "Swift")
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: language)
for (name, value) in mirror.children {
    guard let name = name else { continue }
    print("\(name): \(type(of: value)) = '\(value)'")
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question? `When removing the optional it prints out a nil`.. ???

Comment: Did u try this? @Viktor Kucera

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin I was curious about a reflection of String var. Not the object itself.